Transfinite induction in non-standard logics
I will describe the issue through a concrete example.
We have a class of sets indexed by ordinals. We want to prove a certain property about those sets and an argument by induction works, but this is not a first-order property. For example, suppose that the sets are posets and that the property is the countable chain condition (as far as I know, if in our language we only have an order relation, we cannot express the property "every antichain is countable").
So, can we use induction applied to a formula that is not first-order? And if so, what exactly are we assuming? That is, do we need something beyond $\mathsf{ZFC}$?
An answer for the specific example of the countable chain condition would suffice.

Following Alex Kruckman's comment, can you confirm that something like the following formula is what we apply to induction?
$$\varphi(\alpha)=\forall x[\text{inc}(x)\wedge x\subseteq \mathbb{P}_\alpha\rightarrow \exists p\exists q(p\in x\wedge q\in x\wedge p\leq_\alpha q)]$$where $\leq_\alpha$ is the partial order in $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ and $$\text{inc}(x)=\neg\exists f(f \text{ is an injective function from $x$ to $\omega$}).$$ Being $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$ and $\leq_\alpha$ is definable (because we have already defined the list $\langle \mathbb{P}_\alpha:\alpha\in\text{Ord}\rangle$ of partial orders). And, of course, being $\omega$, an injective function, an ordinal... are definable in the first-order language of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

The ccc is not a first-order formula in the language of partial orders, but it is a first-order formula in the language of set theory. Transfinite induction is a theorem (or rather, a theorem schema) of set theory, and it applies to all formulas in the language of set theory.

@AlexKruckman, thank you. I have edited the question. I don't know if you mean something like that.

Yes, that's right. In general, you should get used to the fact that essentially any mathematical property can be translated into a first-order formula in the language of set theory. This is what makes set theory an adequate foundation for mathematics.

@AlexKruckman, thank you very much. Your comment was very helpful.
